# Could not access AWS through IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-authenticator

In chrome browser, logged into AWS account with user name(`Administrator`) part of `Administrators` group.

Created an IAM user (`Bob`) with Custom managed policy(`Demo1`) as shown below:

### [image]

In firefox, tried to login with user `Bob`, below is the error:

### [image]

`Bob` is part of no group.

### [image]

With or without policy(`Demo1`) attachment to user `Bob`, user `Bob` could not login...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t1.*,t2.*,m3.*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Why user `Bob` cannot login?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the demo1 policy xml.

Comment: @DaveS Query edited.... with or without policy, result is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users do not require any permissions to login to the AWS Management Console. (However, they won't be able to see/do anything to the services themselves.)

Therefore, if you are unable to login to the console, you either have the wrong login information (Account, Username, Password) or the user does not have a Console Password enabled.

In the IAM management console, go to the User and look in the **Security credentials tab** to obtain the right console sign-in link and to verify that a password has been enabled.

Comment: In customer enabled option, I made  the option to Custom password.. it worked

Comment: But trust me, I did the same during creation of user account

Comment: This answer seems to be out of date, in particular, the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @paperskilltrees The Security Credentials tab is still the right place to look. I have updated my answer to clarify that you must click on the User first, then go to that tab.

Answer (score 2):

It is strange that I was not able to login into AWS management console using IAM user information. I went to the root account and copied the console sign-in link for the IAM user, then entered my credentials. It started working.

Comment: Same here. Unable to log in at https://console.aws.amazon.com/console but able to log in via a link.

Comment: It seems there are [two different kinds of users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/signin/latest/userguide/how-to-sign-in.html) in AWS: (1) "IAM user" and (2) "user in IAM Identity Center". The latter is what you and I created and used, and for this kind of users a sign-in link [is required](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/signin/latest/userguide/iam-id-center-sign-in-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot login AIM user(created in AIM identity center) through https://signin.aws.amazon.com/ even though there is an "IAM" option.

But I can always login throught the url *****.awsapps.com, the **** part should be unique to each AIM user. Bookmark this url and login using it.